# Are recursive list comprehensions in python a good idea?

Tags: python

I just found some code like:

```
class C:
    def __init__( self ):
        ...
    def make_widget_tree( self ):
        kids_widgets = [ make_widget_tree( kid ) for kid in self.kids ]
        return Widget( kids = kids_widgets )
```

I can see that it works (and it does), but is it a good idea? I would have written a 'recurse' function to build up the widget tree, but I imagine this code as constructing the resulting tree in a gorgeous explosion of evaluation contexts, which seems somehow wasteful. Does someone have an opinion on this, please?

Comment: It is no more wasteful than using a regular recursive function, but in Python 3 you could run into the recursion limits sooner as more execution frames are used. I've used this plenty of times before, in any case.

Comment: It's simple, easy to read and understand, and works. What's not to like?

Comment: Looks fine to me (though neither me nor pep8 like the spaces around the brackets and parentheses!)

Comment: Well, the real code processes hundreds of thousands of entries and the tree is quite deep, so I was wondering what happens to the python evaluation context in this situation. Sorry if I have the wrong terms but I believe that a function along with its environment is called a 'closure'? It seems to me that the top-level closure might need to instantiate and evaluate all the closures in the tree before it can assemble the top-level list. My worry is that the evaluation of this on large datasets might 'blow up' in terms of the resources it requires.

Comment: As I said I can see that it works and how it works, my concern is only that it might be a poor use of memory resources, when it is easy to see how a recursive function could be written to walk the existing tree and make the new tree without requiring loads  of stack space. As someone who is familiar with how evaluation of C code proceeds, it unnerves me that I cannot easily see how this evaluation might proceed.

Comment: I know the spaces are non-standard, but I think do think it makes it easier to pick out tokens in ones code.